# Rails link_to sends POST and GET requests when you use method: :post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I trying to send a POST request via link_to in the following way:

`link_to 'go to transition', transition_diagnosis_path, method: :post`.

My `DiagnosisController` has the action `transition`, but when I click on the link this sends two requests, a POST and a GET. The first request executes successfully, but the last one sends an unknown parameter to the  `show` action and therefore returns an error.

```
Started POST "/diagnosis/transition" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-08 17:45:32 -0200
Processing by DiagnosisController#transition as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/analysis
Completed 302 Found in 1126ms (ActiveRecord: 128.0ms)

Started GET "/diagnosis/transition" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-08 17:45:33 -0200
Processing by DiagnosisController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"transition"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 975ms (ActiveRecord: 24.8ms)
```

Does anyone know what I should do? Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:

When I try to do this it works normally

```
link_to transition_diagnosis_path, method: :post do
  button_tag 'go to transition'
end
```

Comment: Try adding a `remote: true` option, and see out it behaves

Comment: @DamianSimonPeter add `remote: true` keep the same behavior. Clicking on the link continues sending two requests.

Answer (score 0):

In your transition method in the diagnosis controller, after the action, there is a redirect that is redirecting you - that is what the second get request is.

You could just get rid of the redirect. Delete the part of your transition method that looks like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :nothing => true }
    format.html { redirect_to home_url }
end
```

Also, just make sure your routes are declared

`post 'diagnosis/transition', to: 'diagnosis#transition'`

Comment: Even removing the `redirect_to analysis_path` from the `transition` action,  it still continues to send two requests. The route is declared just like you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to load `jquery_ujs` in `Application.js`